# Multiplatform development using Kivy/Python: Module pygame snag

Tags: python, pygame, kivy, multiplatform

I'm tantalised by the notion of a competitor to Cordova—one based on Python.

I check whether Kivy is available under MacPorts:

```
> port list | grep kivy
py-kivy                        @1.9.1          python/py-kivy
py26-kivy                      @1.9.1          python/py-kivy
py27-kivy                      @1.9.1          python/py-kivy
py35-kivy                      @1.9.1          python/py-kivy
```

I choose one:

```
sudo port install py27-kivy
```

I point at one of the demos:

```
cd /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/share/kivy-examples/tutorials/pong
```

And finally:

```
python main.py
```

That fails:

```
...
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider at all!
pygame - ImportError: No module named pygame
...
```

Should I install pygame

1. by going to pygame's site: http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml
2. through MacPorts, or
3. through pip (and a virtualenv)

?

And is it indeed the case that the freshest I could install will be the "1.9.1 Packages (August 6th 2009)"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, don't install pygame (unless you want to use it for some other reason). Kivy now uses SDL2 as the default backend, so make sure you have that installed and that Kivy can find it to compile against - you'll see build logs about that during compilation.

1.9.1 is the current stable release, and was released about 3 months ago, much more recently than 2009.

Comment: In a separate virtualenv kivy: `(kivy)> pip install libsdl2`, I get: "Collecting libsdl2. Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libsdl2 (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for libsdl2."

Comment: SDL2 is not a python library (and Kivy doesn't need/use the sdl2 python library that does exist, which is a ctypes interface to SDL2). You can download it from its website, or possibly via something like homebrew.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your help. I think the big mistake is assuming that Kivy would work from MacPorts, but this is one of the cases where it's better to stay away from MacPorts and install elsewhere.